# Using windows shell to modify the line after a specific line

Tags: windows, command-line, regex, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I am trying to edit a line right after the line I am searching for. The file used is actually generated from parsing the registry.pol through the LGPO.exe. Here is the sample of the text file:

```
Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
NoChangingLockScreen
DELETE

Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft Services\AdmPwd
PasswordComplexity
DWORD:4

Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft Services\AdmPwd
PasswordLength
DWORD:9

Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft Services\AdmPwd
PasswordAgeDays
DWORD:24
```

I am trying to search for the keyword "PasswordComplexity", afterwords I would look at the next line to edit the data in this case "DWORD:4" to be e.g: "DWORD:12" instead. It would not be possible to simply search for the keyword "DWORD:4" as another setting may have the say key-pair value and it would simply overwrite other settings. How do I edit a specific line just one line below my keyword?

Comment: Hi @PimpJuiceIT, I am planning to automate the whole process with Ansible so it would have to be done on the CLI. Thanks for the suggestion to tag regex, will add it in and hopefully get more opinions for others!

Answer (score 1):

### [file.bat]

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set tmp=
IF EXIST file2.txt DEL file2.txt > nul
FOR /F %%a in (file.txt) do (
    IF "!tmp!"=="PasswordComplexity" (
        IF "%%a"=="DWORD:4" (
            SET tmp=DWORD:12
        ) ELSE (
            SET tmp=%%a
        ) 
    ) ELSE (
        SET tmp=%%a
    )
    IF "!tmp!"=="Computer" echo.>>file2.txt
    echo !tmp! >> file2.txt
)
```

`file.txt` - source script

`file2.txt` - processed script

Comment: Hi @Akina thanks for your solution, however is it there anyway I could turn this .bat file into a list of commands, running this solution with a .bat file would be difficult because I am automating it will Ansible which edits each settings separately as a task, in this case it would be weird to have 200+ .bat files as compared to having 200*number of commands in a single file?

Comment: @pikachu *I am automating it will Ansible [skipped]* You MUST insert this into your question. And in that case .CMD processing is not suitable - use more extended instrument. VBS script, for example.